# How to input Ip address using argv client/server c language

Tags: c, server, clang, client, client-server

i want to sent the argv[0] into the innet
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("%s",argv[0]);

but when i execute it ,it does not work :

error: too many arguments to function ‘inet_addr’
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("%d",argv[0]);

Answer (score 0):

```
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
```

- argv[0] is the program name
- addr is a string, not an int
- server_addr should use htonl  e.g. ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); but thats another story.

I suggest you first inform about the logic of internet and sockets, cos there are differences between server and client.